# How to store coming data persistently?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I use react-native.

And this is the function that I want to use.
The most important point here is `editCommentMutation`.

In order to execute this mutation, it requires two variables which are `id` and `payload`.

```
  const onUpdateComment = React.useCallback((commentId) => {
    setEdit(true);
    console.log(commentId, comments);
    editCommentMutation({
      variables: {
        id: parseInt(commentId),
        payload: comments,
      },
    });
  }, []);
```

I get these two variables correctly.

[image]

For `id` , I get it from component screen. So It comes thru `argument`.
For `payload`, I get it on the same screen.

Problem here is when I press `button1`, it sends `commentId(id)` data from component screen to this page.

And when I press `button2`, it sends `comments(payload)` data on this page.

On this App, I press **button1** and write comments then **button2** in order.

So Each data comes not together, but one by one.

So I execute `console.log(commentId, comments)`,

- press button1 : `386 undefined`
- press button2 : `undefined Object { "comments": "뭐야", }`

It has `undefined` for sure..
But in order to execute mutation, I need two data together.

For this, I need to save coming data in somewhere, I guess.

I also tried
`const [data, setData] = useState("")`.

After I save coming commentId to here as:
`setData(commentId)`.

But it isn't saved, just disappears. :)

Can you help me?

Comment: you can use any state management like redux to persist your data

Comment: you mean useState? But I tried to use useState as I wrote above. but it doesn't work. I'm a beginner and I haven't used redux yet, I've only used react-native. can you help me more with example? I will study.

Comment: I understand that you mean I should study redux and it's not possible without it, right?

Comment: Note `commentId` should be included in your `useCallback` dependencies - `useCallback(..., [commentId])`. See [useCallback docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) noted section.

Comment: If you are using GraphQL for the mutation, consider adding the `graphql` tag to the question. You do not need Redux to solve this problem. Don't add dependencies to your project without understanding what benefits they provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal verifiable example. Run the code below and

1. click <kbd>✏️</kbd> to edit one of the comments
2. click <kbd>✅</kbd> to save your edit and view the updated comment

```js
function App() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(null)
  const [comments, setComments] = React.useState([ "hello", "안녕하세요" ])
  const onEdit = editable => event => { setEdit(editable) }
  const onUpdate = newComment => event => {
    /* execute your graphql mutation here */
    setComments([
       ...comments.slice(0, edit.index),
       newComment,
       ...comments.slice(edit.index + 1)
    ])
    setEdit(null)
  }
  return <div>
    {comments.map((comment, index) =>
      <p>{comment}
        <button
          children="✏️"
          onClick={onEdit({comment, index})}
          disabled={Boolean(edit)}
        />
      </p>
    )}
    {edit ? <EditComment text={edit.comment} onUpdate={onUpdate} /> : null}
  </div>
}
function EditComment({ text, onUpdate }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(text)
  return <div>
    <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={onUpdate(value)} children="✅" />
  </div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
button[disabled] { opacity: 0.5; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In your App you will execute your mutation in `onUpdate`. A cancel button <kbd>❌</kbd> can easily be defined using `const onCancel = event => { setEdit(null) }` and pass it to `EditComment`.

Comment: thanks I have a question. I learn from somewhere that I need to change cache manually in React when I edit or delete, but you don't. what is the difference?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "change the cache"?

Comment: as fas as I know, cache is record. sometimes, when I delete the comment, it is deleted from server, but not on UI. so we manually change cache to delete that comment. My understanding is when we put change in useState, then state changes and UI is mounted automatically so we don't need to manually change cache but otherwise (don't put in state) we change cache. is that correct?

Comment: If there is a common pattern in React Native, I'm not sure. For web, typically you execute the persistence query, such as GraphQL mutation or REST delete request. If it succeeds, then you update the state in the UI. In the code example I wrote, there is no DB persistence, but I included the update the local app state. I left a comment `/* execute your GraphQL mutation here */` where your DB persistence query would go. Note DB updates are not required every time state changes in your app. Most state changes on `useState` values are local and do not require persistence or synchronization.

Comment: GraphQL is useful here because `mutation` queries can return selected data too. In the case of "create" and "edit" mutations, the selected data is used to update the local state in the app. For "delete" you can select an `id` and remove that a comment by that id. The same is possible with REST but GraphQL is more flexible.

Comment: This is very insightful answer. If you could put `onUpdate` and `value` together into a custom hook, and `edit` and `onEdit` into another hook, I'll appreciate it.