# React hooks depends on another state can cause infinite loop. Why is that?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two hooks, one of which depends on the other state. I wrote two patterns to handle it. When `useEffect` is in custom hooks (and I want to hide `useEffect` into a custom hook), it causes an infinite loop. Why is that? Thanks.

**Infinite loop version**

hooks.ts

```
  const useUpdate = (initialValue) => {
    [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(initialValue)
    useEffect(() => {
      setSelectedItem(initialValue)
    }, [initialValue])
    const update = () => {...}
    return update
  }
```

MyComponent.ts

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectecItem] = useSelectItem()
  const update = useUpdate(selectedItem)
  return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

**Success version**

hooks.ts

```
const useUpdate = (initialValue) => {
  [selectedItem, setSelectedItemInUpdate] = useState(initialValue)
  const update = () => {...}
  return {update, setSelectedItemInUpdate}
}
```

MyComponent.tsx

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectecItem] = useSelectItem()
  const {update, setSelectedItemInUpdate} = useUpdate(selectedItem)
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedItemInUpdate(selectedItem)
  }, [selectedItem])
  return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

---

Edited (2022/03/07) to answer a comment, contents of custom hooks are shown below. They are still not entire source code, but it can give much more context. `useUpdate`'s `return` type isn't consistent with the above description.

```
const useSelectItem = (initialValue: Item[] =[]) => {
  // Select and unselect one item.
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<Item[]>(initialValue)
  const select = (item: Item) => {
    if (selectedItem.at(0) === item) {
      // if already selected, unselect it.
      selectedItem([])
    } else {
      selectedItem([item])
    }
  }
  return [selectedItem, select]
}

// useUpdate should operate on a selectedItem
const useUpdate = () => {
  // keep shallow copy of selectedItem to edit locally.
  const [item, setItem] = useState<Item|undefined>(undefined)
  const onChangeName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setItem({...item, {[name]: event.target.value}
  }
  const update = async () => {
    // write to firestore provided by Firebase, Google.
    await updateDoc(doc(db, 'items', item.id), item)
  }
  //  ... and many other functions to operate on input field.
  return {onChangeName, update, and many others}

}
```

Of course these hooks can be combined into one hook, but I think I have to separate them so that they have a single responsibility.

Comment: This looks like an anti-pattern. Can you share the contents of `const update = …` and `useSelectItem`?

Comment: Hi. This pattern happens in many places. calling `const {currentUser} = useAuth; const data = useUserData(currentUser)`. In this post, I have user list. An admin user can select a user and update/delete it. Selecting a user and operating a user should be in the different hooks. However, update operation and delete operation should get a selected user. In that sense, it depends on another state. I don't want to call as few `useEffect` as possible in container level component. So I wanted to move `useEffect` into my custom update hooks, and end up observing an infinite loop. Thanks for asking

Comment: right but can you update the post to show the contents of `useSelectItem` and `const update ...`?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question description and added more information.

Comment: I can't see a need for `useEffect` in the infinite loop code. `setSelectedItem` *is* the effect and can be set to `onClick` or whichever event needs to trigger that effect. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71201723/18200347) for a functioning demo that does something similar. It would be more helpful if you could post `useUpdate` in full.

Comment: Thank you. Your functioning demo is exactly as the same situation as mine. I wanted to make two custom hooks for `select` and `edit`. In your demo, `const onEdit = editable => event => { setEdit(editable) }` connects two hooks. That the point I brought `useEffect` for `edit` hooks to monitor `select` state. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because of `useEffect dependency array`. In the infinite loop version of `useEffect`, `initialValue` is changing constantly, and it is causing the infinite loop.

Try changing it to the below code.

```
   const useUpdate = (initialValue) => {
       [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(initialValue)
       useEffect(() => {
       setSelectedItem(initialValue)
       //eslint-disable-next-line
       }, [])
       const update = () => {...}
       return update
  }
```

`//eslint-disable-next-line` won't give you warnings because of empty `dependency array'

Answer (score 0):

As Dharmik Patel's answer stated, the issue is likely caused by the `dependency array`. Another way you can get around the issue, without disabling eslint is to `useMemo`.

```js
   const useUpdate = (initialValue) => {
       const initial = useMemo(() => initialValue, [initialValue])
       [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(initialValue)
       useEffect(() => {
       setSelectedItem(initial)
       }, [initial])
       const update = () => {...}
       return update
  }
```

The useMemo will ensure that re-renders only occur if the value of `initialValue` changes. However [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/rethinking-hooks-memoization/) explains an even better way to do this than using useMemo.